# reduce the size of tooltip arrow

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to reduce the size of tooltip which is loaded in jquery.Now the arrow appear in big size.I reed to reduce the size of arrow and should be appeared in middle whatever the size of the text

```js
jQuery(function(){
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
        // Hover over code
        var title = jQuery(this).attr('data-original-title');
        jQuery(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        jQuery('<p class="notetool fade top in"></p>')
        .text(title)
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
        // Hover out code
        jQuery(this).attr('title', jQuery(this).data('tipText'));
        jQuery('.notetool').remove();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
        var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
        jQuery('.notetool')
        .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
});
  });
});
```

```css
.notetool {
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 color: #0f0025;
     background-color: #FFEF93;
     border: 1px solid #F1D031;
 border-radius:5px;
 padding:10px;
 font-size:12px Arial;
} 
.notetool:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 40%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid black;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" class="masterTooltip" data-original-title=" IPL?" title="IPL?"> IPL?</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reduce the side of the borders not the width since the arrow is buit based on borders.
For the popover position you can manipulate that using the `left` and `top` 
What I have noticed is that you are getting the **horizontal** position from mouse position wish is not fine.

```
jQuery('.notetool')
        .css({ top: mousey, left: 0 });
```

```js
jQuery(function(){
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
        // Hover over code
        var title = jQuery(this).attr('data-original-title');
        jQuery(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        jQuery('<p class="notetool fade top in"></p>')
        .text(title)
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
        // Hover out code
        jQuery(this).attr('title', jQuery(this).data('tipText'));
        jQuery('.notetool').remove();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
        //var mousex = e.pageX; //Get X coordinates
        var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
        jQuery('.notetool')
        .css({ top: mousey, left: 0 })
});
  });
});
```

```css
.notetool {
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 color: #0f0025;
  background-color: #FFEF93;
  border: 1px solid #F1D031;
 border-radius:5px;
 padding:10px;
 font-size:12px Arial;
} 
.notetool:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 30%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid black;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" class="masterTooltip" data-original-title=" IPL?" title="IPL?"> IPL?</a>
```

Comment: how to make it to display in center

Comment: The arrow or the hole popover ?

Comment: both popover and arrow